# Using JustMock With Sitecore 8.2.4 Kernel DLL

Tags: upgrade, unit-testing

I have the following JustMock call in my old 8.0.7 Sitecore project:

```
var siteGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
var siteItem = Mock.Create<Item>();
var id = new ID(siteGuid);
Mock.Arrange(() => siteItem.ID).Returns(id);
Mock.Arrange(() => Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem(Arg.AnyString)).Returns(siteItem);
```

The same call is duplicated in my upgraded project. As part of the upgrade, the Sitecore Client and Kernel dlls were updated to their new versions. I'm currently using JustMock version 2016.2.426.1 for both projects.

When I run the test on the 8.0.7 project I can see the following output when I watch the Sitecore.Context.Database variable:

[image: 8.0.7 Sitecore.Context.Database watch]

As you can see, the Sitecore variables in this object are mapped to null.

When I run the same test on the 8.2.4 project I get the following output:

[image: 8.2.4 Sitecore.Context.Database watch]

Here I get exception values for all of the Sitecore properties. When I drill into the exception a bit I can see that it displays:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Castle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

These exception values in the Sitecore.Context.Database object are causing many tests to break.

I'm a bit at a loss for what's going on here. I know it has to be related to updating the version of Sitecore.Kernel but I'm not sure why this would cause the test to break in this way. Any ideas on where to go from here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of Castle Windsor is in your `bin` directory? Is the Castle Windsor lib referenced in your test project?

Comment: There is no reference to Castle.Windsor in the either the 8.0.7 test project or the 8.2.4 test project. There is a reference to Castle.Core version 3.3.0.0 in both the 8.0.7 and 8.2.4 versions of the project. Removing or updating the Castle.Core reference appeared to have no effect on the test pass/fail. Adding a reference to Castle.Windsor did not have an effect either.

Comment: Sorry I meant Castle Core, rather than Windsor. The error looks like a .net binding failure. These happen when there's the wrong version of a dll, or the reference is missing, or the reference is targeting the wrong framework version (mostly)